# How to allow drop only within the bounds of an object (picturebox)

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code I have so far:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int maxX, minX, maxY, minY;

    minX = pictureBox2.Location.X;
    minY = pictureBox2.Location.Y;
    maxX = (pictureBox2.Size.Width) + minX;
    maxY = (pictureBox2.Size.Height) + minY;

    Point PictureLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

    if (   (PictureLocation.X <= maxX)
        && (PictureLocation.X >= minX)
        && (PictureLocation.Y <= maxY)
        && (PictureLocation.Y >= minY)   )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The drag is working");
        //Rest of the program is fine
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please re-drag the item into the area");
    }
}
```

At the moment all it comes up with is the else statement and I can't quite figure out why.

ADDITIONAL:
If it helps, I am also using a faint form during the drag in this way which could effect the position as I've found that the ABOVE CODE HAS A CORRECT ZONE to the right and below of where I need it:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mdown = e.Location;
    form2.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
    form2.BackgroundImage = pictureBox1.Image;
    form2.Opacity = 0.5f;
    form2.MaximizeBox = false;
    form2.ControlBox = false;
    form2.Text = "";
    form2.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    form2.Size = new Size(150, 150);
    form2.Show();
    Point pt = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location);
    form2.Location = pt;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Point pt = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(new Point(-(form2.Width / 2) + e.X, -(form2.Height / 2) + e.Y));
        form2.Location = pt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point you are given by `e.X` and `e.Y` is relative to the control that raised the event (the picturebox).

So you actually want:

```
minX = 0;
minY = 0;
maxX = pictureBox2.Size.Width;
maxY = pictureBox2.Size.Height;
```

Comment: Apologies, I had the wrong picturebox numbers in my first edit, please see the revision with picturebox2's

Comment: Ah, this is Picturebox1 checking on Picturebox2. You know there are `Drag` events you could be using?

Answer (score 0):

as the first picture box was taking a datum at it's own location 0,0, so by using that, and the fact that my pictureboxes are on the same y location starting you get this:

```
minX = (pictureBox2.Location.X)-(pictureBox1.Location.X);
minY = 0;
maxX = ((pictureBox2.Location.X) - (pictureBox1.Location.X)) + (pictureBox2.Width);
maxY = 0 + (pictureBox2.Height);
```

Thanks for everyone's help!